# Create a procedure in SQL that allows me to add new inputs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a procedure that allows me to add new flights. The flight can have an existing airline and origin/destination, but it also allows me to add new cities and airlines. I can't make the query to allow me to add new inputs to the table.

**My tables:**

```
                                             FLIGHTS
NumFlight  |       Date          | Origin |Destination|  Airline  | NumPassengers | International|
___________|_____________________|________|___________|___________|_______________|______________|
44             2014-02-08            2          3           3           135              Yes
76             2014-03-17            2          1           2            80              No
380            2014-06-04            5          1           2           147              No
421            2014-04-21            1          2           1           185              No
572            2014-09-12            5          4           3            99              Yes
906            2014-05-10            3          2           3           154              Yes
918            2014-12-24            1          5           1           122              No
```

```
           AIRLINES
   AirlineID  |   Name    |
______________|___________|
       1         Delta
       2         United
       3        Air France
```

```
             CITY
    CityID    |      City       |
______________|_________________|
      1           Chicago
      2           New York
      3           Paris
      4           Madrid
      5           Houston
```

**My query**:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE NEW_FLIGHT (@NumFlight int, @Date date, @OriginID int, @OriginName varchar(40), @DestinationID int,@DestinationName varchar(40), @AirlineID int, @AirlineName varchar(40), @NumPassengers int, @Internacional varchar(4)) AS

    IF @AirlineName not in (SELECT Name FROM AIRLINES)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ID_AE AS INT
        SET @ID_AE = (SELECT MAX(AirlineID) + 1 FROM AIRLINES)
        INSERT INTO AIRLINES VALUES (@ID_AE, @AirlineName)
    END

    IF @OriginName not in (SELECT City FROM CITY) OR @DestinationName not in (SELECT City FROM CITY)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ID_CI AS INT
        SET @ID_CI = (SELECT MAX(CityID) + 1 FROM CITY)
        INSERT INTO CITY VALUES (@ID_CI,@OriginName)
    END

    ELSE
    IF @AirlineName in (SELECT Name FROM AIRLINES) AND  (@OriginName in (SELECT City FROM CITY) AND @DestinationName in (SELECT City FROM CITY))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AIRLINES VALUES(@NumFlight, @Date, @OriginID, @DestinationID, @AirlineID, @NumPassengers, @Internacional)
END;
```

Comment: It is a very basic question. You can search for tutorials on SQL Insert queries. I give a [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/crud-operations-sql-server/).

Comment: *I don't have a query because everything I tried failed"* Then you have queries, they just didn't work. Include your attempt(s).

Comment: hey @rookielander as they mentioned above its a very basic question, but take note that ideally you should have 3 differents stored procedures, one for each table you wannna add new records to

Comment: I already put my tried query, it's a mess so I apologize beforehand.

Comment: @rookielander You check whether `@OriginName` *or* `@DestinationName` is not currently a known city. But then based on that test, you only have an insert for the new `@OriginName`. What if only the `@DestinationName` is a new city? What if *both* are new cities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to have a single query in each stored procedure for better execution plans and maintainability.

The first would be the insert into airline table.  This returns the newly inserted ID as well to improve user front end so the front end can know which item was recently added to the airline select.  Make sure to also have a UNIQUE constraint on the Name column to ensure duplicates are not inserted.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procAirline_ADD
   @Name varchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO AIRLINES (Name)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.AirlineID
   VALUES (@Name)
END
```

Then you have the insert for the city table which returns a newly generated ID.  Again make sure you have a UNIQUE constraint on the City column to ensure duplicates are not inserted.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procCity_ADD
   @City varchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO CITY (City)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.CityID
   VALUES (@City)
END
```

Lastly you have the insert for the flights table.  No need to pass the names to this procedures since those are handled in the previous procedures.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procFlights_ADD 
   @Date date, 
   @OriginID int, 
   @DestinationID int, 
   @AirlineID int, 
   @NumPassengers int, 
   @Internacional varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Flights (
      Date,
      Origin,
      Destination,
      Airline,
      NumPassengers,
      International)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.NumFlight
   VALUES (
      @Date,
      @OriginID,
      @DestinationID,
      @AirlineID,
      @NumPassengers,
      @Internacional
   )
END
```

As a last note, you probably noticed I did not pass in AirlineID to procAirline_ADD, CityID to procCity_ADD, or NumFlight to procFlight_ADD.  It is easier if you let the database handle the generation of IDs by adding identity constraints to those columns.